# Do these three vectors build a base of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find third vector to build a base of $\mathbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245623/find-third-vector-to-build-a-base-of-mathbbr3)

> For the following vectors $v_1 = \left(\begin{matrix}
> 1  \\
> 1  \\
> 2 
> \end{matrix}\right)$ and $v_2 = \left(\begin{matrix}
> 2  \\
> 2  \\
> 5 
> \end{matrix}\right)$, find a third vector $v_3 = \left(\begin{matrix}
> x  \\
> y  \\
> z 
> \end{matrix}\right)$ which together build a base for $\mathbb{R}^3$.*

**My solution**

We know that the vectors must be linearly independent, so

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & x \\
1 & 2 & y \\
2 & 5 & z
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
{\lambda}_1 \\
{\lambda}_2 \\
{\lambda}_3
\end{matrix}\right) = 
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

for ${\lambda}_1 = {\lambda}_2 = {\lambda}_3 = 0$

The gauss reduction gives

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & x \\
0 & 1 & z-2x \\
0 & 0 & y-x
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

So the solution would be any vector $v_3$ for which the following hold:

$$
y \neq x \\
z \neq 2x \\
x \neq 0
$$

for example $$
\left(\begin{matrix}
1  \\
2  \\
3 
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Is this a valid solution?

Comment: You only need $y\neq x$ as a condition for the third vector be LI with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good approach and the answer is correct. when you think about what you would do with the Gauss reduction, it is only required that the bottom right entry $y-z$ is non-zero for the third vector to be linearly independent from the other two.

Comment: So if I would get the bottom right $0$ after the reduction, then the first two vectors are already linearly dependent and there's no way to find $v_3$ such that the condition is right?

Comment: Correct. You can only increase the dimension of the column space by 1 with each additional vector.

Answer (score 1):

After the reduction, the determinant of the matrix is $y-x$, so you get a basis if and only if $x \neq y$.

An alternative way to describe this, is that the first two vectors are not colinear, so they span a plane in $\Bbb R^3$. It is also obvious that they span the plane of equation $x=y$ because both vectors satisfy that equation. So in order to get a basis, you only need to add a vector which is not in that plane, that means a vector $(x,y,z)$ with $x \neq y$.